# getting "Terminated" message from running shell script

Tags: shell-script

I'm getting a `Terminated` output upon running my shell script.
The script is huge and confidential so I can't post it here, but I can confirm there are no `kill` commands in the script.

Unfortunately I can't seem to find out what the problem is, as the "Terminated" output is only happening on one out of several servers.

I've set the debug flag and ran it before, but I got a rather uninformative

```
+ main
+ 1>> /home/user/app/logs/msg.log 2>& 1
Terminated
```

Portion of script this corresponds to

```
main "$@" >> $LOG 2>&1

gzip $LOG
```

Would appreciate some suggestions, thank you.

Comment: Could you say something about what shell the script is written for?

Comment: It looks like the expansion of `$@` causes `main "$@" >> $LOG 2>&1` to be split into two  separate commands. Did you check the contents of `$@`?

Comment: "Terminated" usually happens when the kernel (the OOM killer) kills the process because it was using too much memory. What is the script doing?